# Technical-Scientific Writing

Tags: grammar

I have just turned in a paper on engines, but I keep thinking about a sentence I wrote:

Plug-in hybrids offer a variant since they work with the electric engine for longer periods, being still more eco-friendly.

Is it acceptable to use "offer a variant" in this context? What I meant was hybrids are an alternative vehicle.

Comment: I'd say things *offer* an alternative, and things *are* a variant.   Your sentence is not quite right.

Comment: @Jim I agree with you, unfortunately.

Comment: An option is to use "option" as an alternative to "alternative".

Comment: If you've just turned in the paper, forget about it.  There are more important things to anguish over.  (The wording in not ideal, but it's not that bad either.  "Variant" is actually better than "alternative" in the sense that it suggests a relative minor difference between two similar things, vs a whole new paradigm.)

Comment: (But perhaps you meant to say "offer a variation on the plain hybrid".)

Answer (score 1):

First thought was 'offer a variant *what*?'.

Did you exclude ***alternative*** for a reason?

> Plug-in hybrids offer an *alternative* since they work with the electric engine for longer periods ...
>
> (... furthermore, they are still more eco-friendly.)

Comment: Yes, I excluded it for the sake of avoiding repetition. And I meant to use "variant" as a noun, not as an adjective.